# Reading first few lines from files in google cloud storage

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

While processing huge files ~100GB file size, sometime we need to check first/last few lines (header and trailer lines).

The easy option is to download entire file locally using

```
gsutil cp gs://bucket_name/file_name .
```

and then use head/tail command to check header/trailer lines which is not feasible as it will be time consuming and associated cost of extracting data from cloud.

It is same as performing -

```
gsutil cat gs://bucket_name/file_name | head -1
```

The other option is to create external table in GCP Tables OR visualize them in datastudio OR read from dataproc cluster/VM.

Is there any other quick option just to check header/trailer lines from cloud storage ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
gsutil cat -r
```

is the key here.

It output just the specified byte range of object. Offsets starts with 0.

Eg.
To return bytes from 10th to 100th position from the file :

```
gsutil cat -r 10-100 gs://bucket_name/file_name
```

To return bytes from 100th till end of file :

```
gustil cat -r 100- gs://bucket_name/file_name
```

To return last 10 bytes from the files :

```
gsutil cat -r -10 gs://bucket_name/file_name
```